# Getting confusing error when using Qprocess.start(programname, ListofStringArguments) Need some clarity

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

Some odd reaction with PyQt5.8 on windows 10. I'm making this because I want to try to **understand** why I get this problem, as it's easily solved. (Shown below)

I try to do:

```
Command =''' testurl  -x --audio-format "mp3" --audio-quality "0"'''
self.start('yotube-dl',Command.split())
```

but get the error from youtube-dl that the specified audio format is wrong. Which means that for some reason, `"mp3"` isn't after `--audio-format`. I also tried, `--audio-format="mp3"`, and that also gives me an error, despite not having a space after the `--audio-format`

Now, if I do my "workaround":

```
self.start('youtube-dl'+Command)
```

It works as expected. It tells you the specified URL(since it's `testurl`) is not valid. Don't be mistakes, a working url behaves just the same. So, obviously one would think there's something funky with the `.split()` part of it, but this is how the list turns out when you use `Command.split()`:

```
['testurl', '-x', '--audio-format', '"mp3"', '--audio-quality', '"0"']
```

And as far as I know, the arguments are passed in order of the list. I've had it working before, but as soon as I changed another configuration, it all went south. I just can't figure out why my results differ, and it's only for this specific audio conversion argument(`-x --audio-format "mp3"`), other arguments work pretty well, one of them containing spaces.

Also, I can let you know I tried with lots of `"`'s around in the string, and to no help. I'm presuming this has something to do with the way `"` are added in some places on windows according to Qt documentation([Link for reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start)), but I still can't make figure out what to change. For all I know, it's something stupid i'm doing.

So, if anyone has understanding of why it does this, i'd love to know. Again, i'm just looking for some clarity, as I already worked around it, but want to understand why it goes wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the double-quotes.

Comment: @ekhumoro, well, I tested that at least two times before with no luck, so i can't fathom why it works now :/ Regardless, thanks a lot though!